# PHP within jQuery using a var within .attr

Tags: jquery

I have created a variable like this: `var imageUrl   = <?php $local_path . 'images/';?>`

How could I use this variable `imageUrl` within `.attr()`? I currently have `.attr("src", imageUrl.val + response[0][""]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `imageUrl` is a plain variable it has no `val()` method, you can access it directly. Also note that as the PHP code returns a string, you need to wrap the JS value in quotes. Try this:

```
var imageUrl = '<?php $local_path . 'images/'; ?>';
$element.attr("src", imageUrl + response[0][""])
```

Comment: Thanks, but then it shows `<img src="[object Object]filename.jpg">`

Comment: Then you need to set `$local_path` to the correct value, not an object. Can you edit your question to show how you're currently setting it.